# Profile Photo Upload

Tags: php

I thinking to create a option whereby a user able to upload photo to their profile in a website.

When a user upload a photo, a folder with the user login ID can be generated inside a root folder "C:\wamp\www". In other words, each user will have a folder store their profile image, folder name will be the user id.

This is my first project on PHP and I am not sure what I have thought of can be possibly done. 
I will need some aid and guide to move further. I will appreciate and make full use of any references given here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?php
   if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
   {
   echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
   }
  else
  {
  echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
  echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
  echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
  echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br />";

  $UserId   =   $_SESSION_USER_ID;
  $path =   "C://wamp/www/images/";
  mkdir($path,$UserId);
if (file_exists($path. $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
  {
  echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
  }
else
  {
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
  $path . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
  echo "Stored in: " . $path . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
  }
  }
 ?>
```

Here , $_SESSION_USER_ID is your user login ID and it will create directory inside C://wamp/www/images/ and upload images in appropriate directory.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to fully read [this tutorial](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) on how to upload files using PHP. There are numerous other tutorials on how to upload files using PHP. just google "PHP file upload". If you got something to show or have any problems understanding, just ask. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You should bear in mind that most systems have a limit on the number of sub-directories and files that a directory can hold.  Have a look at this answer for some alternative suggestions for organizing your directory structure https://superuser.com/questions/66331/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-folders-allowed-in-a-folder-in-linux.  Alternatively, any serious implementation would look at Mongo GridFS to hold the images in a database, rather than in separate files.